# How to use a value from the CSV in the chart?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

So this is the Code with the data, and I'd like a way that instead of having "value:1", I could have value:"data.csv", line 1, row 15, for example so I can load them from the data instead of having to type them. Is that possible? Thanks!

```
        var dataNorte = [
              [
              {axis:"Alcohol",value:1},
              {axis:"Mother's Habilitations",value:0.57},
              {axis:"Father's Habilitations",value:0.71},
              {axis:"Failures",value:0.33},
              {axis:"Tobacco",value:0.4},
              {axis:"Age",value:0.44}
              ]
            ];
```

Comment: just create a CSV file and load with `d3.csv`

Comment: Yeah but how do I do that, I've tried and the chart disappears when I load the page.

Comment: find a working example for the version of d3 that you use

Comment: So a new question would be how could i change the first "value:1" for "value:x" and make that x=1 ?